# How to calculate range in 1 week using Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
tanggal    | product
2021-01-01   bag 1
2021-01-05   bag 5
2021-01-08   bag 8
2021-01-11   bag 11
2021-01-12   bag 12
2021-01-13   bag 13
2021-01-14   bag 14
```

here I have a product tbl, in this table there are input dates and product names,
I want to calculate the product based on 1 week how the query to calculate the data with a range of 7 days?

and this my query

```
select tanggal, product from tbl_product
where tanggal > current_date + interval '7' day
```

Comment: Can you also add the exact expected results?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all.  What results do you want?

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this for arbitrary dates using a generated time series.

For example:

```sql
SELECT series::date 
FROM generate_series(
        (now() - interval '1 week')::date,
        now()::date,
        '1 day'::interval
) series;
```

Would result in:

```
2021-05-26
2021-05-27
2021-05-28
2021-05-29
2021-05-30
2021-05-31
2021-06-01
2021-06-02
```

which you can join with other tables as you see fit.

For further information on `generate_series()` and other set-returning functions, check out the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html).

Comment: I want to count the products in the first, second and third week of this month. more like that

Comment: If this answer was what you were looking for, please consider accepting it so that others that stumble upon this question know that it has been answered. If not, posting your own answer would help others that come after. :)